# WooCommerce Simple Auctions add username to auction finished email

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Really hope someone can help. I'm using Woocommerce Simple auctions and need to include the username of the person who won the auction in a woocommerce email template auction_finish.php.

The following code is provided by the developer;

```
<?php $wining_user_id = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_auction_current_bider', true );
$user = get_userdata ( $wining_user_id ); ?>
```

I then added this;

```
<?php echo 'Username: ' . $user->username . ; ?>
```

Sadly, no dice, I see the **Username:** text in the email but not the actual username.

In a support ticket, the developer only supplied me with the following: **$user variable has user data, you need to output it like echo $user->username;**

Can someone maybe help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it our:

```
<?php $user_info = get_userdata(1);
      echo 'Winning bidder e-email address: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `->user_email` for the email address? And whilst it ought to be safe I'd probably esc_html() that anyway.